# bash script join illegal usage

Tags: bash

```
tab="`echo | perl -pe 's//\t/'`"
if [ -e port ]
then
    cat port | sort -n >! port_s.sorted
    cat port_s | sort -n >! port_sw.sorted

    join -v 1 port_sw.sorted  port_s.sorted
    join -v 1 port_sw.sorted  port_ssorted >! "${new}
    join -t "$tab" port_swaps_new_durs.sorted port_swaps_old_durs.sorted >! audit_port_swaps.tmp
    awk -F"$tab" '{if [ ($2 != "NaN") && ($2 != 0) && ((abs($2 - $3)/$2) > 0.05) ] print}' \
      audit_port_swaps.tmp >! audit_port_swaps.tmp2
    count=`cat audit_port_swaps.tmp2 | wc -l`
```

The above is the part of bash script,i am getting usage error for join commands and syntax error near line 1in awk.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
error-
usage: join [-a file_number | -v file_number] [-o list [-e string]]
            [-t char] [-1 field] [-2 field] file1 file2

       join [-a file_number] [-j field] [-j1 field] [-j2 field]
            [-o list [-e string]] [-t char] file1 file2
usage: join [-a file_number | -v file_number] [-o list [-e string]]
            [-t char] [-1 field] [-2 field] file1 file2

       join [-a file_number] [-j field] [-j1 field] [-j2 field]
            [-o list [-e string]] [-t char] file1 file2
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1
```

Comment: did you read the `man join` entry? (There are a lot of other issues with this code, but get 2 good input files and then get your join cmd to output your required output from the cmd line). Good luck.

Comment: First fix the obvious typos: add the missing double quote after `>! "${new}`, and replace the square brackets in the `if` statement in the awk code by parentheses. Then try again.

Comment: What is the `>!` redirection? I'm aware of `>|` for when `noclobber` is set.

Comment: @glennjackman That's the (shudder) `csh` equivalent of `>|`...

Answer (score 2):

1. You're missing a closing quote, though from the error I suspect that's a copy-and-paste problem

   ```
   join -v 1 port_sw.sorted  port_ssorted >! "${new}
   ```
2. Your `$tab` has a newline you don't want. I suspect this is the real reason. This is a creative way to get a tab, but rather convoluted and, ultimately, wrong.

   ```
   tab="`echo | perl -pe 's//\t/'`"
   ```

   Use `$'\t'` instead

   ```
   awk -F $'\t' '{if [ ($2...
   ```

   Or, since it's awk, which interprets escapes properly, just `'\t'`.

   ```
   awk -F'\t' '{if [ ($2...
   ```
3. Awk doesn't use the shell `[` syntax, it's a standard c-like language as far as command structures. Incidentally, this means you don't need spaces all over like you would in the shell.

   ```
   awk -F '\t' '{if(($2 != "NaN") && ...
   ```
4. Not technically an error per se, but you should use `$(...)` instead of `` `...` ``.

   ```
   count=$(cat audit... | wc -l)
   ```
5. Most command line utilities, including `wc` let you specify a file name on the command line. However, `wc` will print the filename too if you do that; you could use `awk` to get just the count (advantage: strips whitespace), or just use shell redirection. Same with `sort`, earlier in the file.

   ```
   count=$(wc -l auditfile.txt | awk '{print $2}')
   count=$(awk 'END{print $NR}' auditfile.txt)
   count=$(wc -l < auditfile.txt)
   ```
6. Instead of repeating the same line (and potentially making a typo in one, like you have here), you should use `tee`.

   ```
   join -v 1 port_sw.sorted  port_s.sorted | tee "$new"
   ```

Comment: Fantastic answer. Just a note, awk treats the 2 character string `"\t"` as a tab, so you can say: `awk -F '\t' ...` without having to use bash's ANSI-C quoting

Comment: Thanks kevin..But awk error seems to be resolved. but still usage issues with join-                                                                 if [ -e port_swaps.old ]
then
cat port_swaps.old | sort -n >! port_swaps_old.sorted
 cat port_swaps.txt | sort -n >! port_swaps_new.sorted
 join -v 1 port_swaps_new.sorted  port_swaps_old.sorted
 join -v 1 port_swaps_new.sorted  port_swaps_old.sorted >! "${new_cusip_file}"
usage: join [-a file_number | -v file_number] [-o list [-e string]]
[-t char] [-1 field] [-2 field] file1 file2
join [-a file_number] [-j field] [-j1 field] [-j2 field]
....

Comment: I'm not getting any errors like that. Try on the command line to get the simplest example you can of a join command that works and one that gives you your error.